# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left(a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta\right) \,d\theta$ where $a,b$ are finite natural numbers

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left(a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta\right) \,d\theta$$ where $a,b$ are finite natural numbers

I have spent about a day thinking over this problem.  I tried integration by parts, differentiating under integral sign (Feynman's trick, with respect to $a, b$), using some trigonometric and logarithmic properties like changing $\cos^2\theta$ to $\cos2\theta$ and hereafter some logarithmic properties, etc.,  but failed miserably.

Also tried to use the property that $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx$$ in-between, but still to no avail. I also tried to find similar questions on MSE but did not get a related one.

Can someone please help me to solve this integral?

Edit

My try (Feynman's trick) :

Let $$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left(a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta\right) d\theta$$

Hence $$I'(a) =\frac 1a \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {2a^2\cos^2\theta d\theta}{a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta}$$ $$=\frac 1a\left[ \frac {\pi}{2}+\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {a^2\cos^2\theta -b^2\sin^2\theta}{a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta}\right]$$

Wherein between I broke $2a^2\cos^2\theta=a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta+a^2\cos^2\theta -b^2\sin^2\theta$

But now how do I continue further

Comment: Feynman's trick works like a charm here, can you show your attempt in full detail?

Comment: I agree with Jack.  Feynman's trick works here.

Comment: "finite natural numbers" ? You can omit the "finite".

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I have edited my try accordingly. Can you please provide some hints further or any different parameter of differentiation in the same method

Comment: The integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2\cos^2\theta-b^2\sin^2\theta}{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta$$ can be simply computed through the substitution $\theta=\arctan u$ and partial fraction decomposition. It equals $\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{a-b}{a+b}$, assuming that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

Comment: a somehow different approach:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926279/how-to-approach-solving-int-0-pi-2-lna2-cos2-x-b2-sin2-x-dx/1926505#1926505

Answer (score 6):

Let $I(a,b)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(a^2\cos^2(\theta)+b^2\sin^2(\theta))\,d\theta$.  Differentiating under the integral with respect to $a^2$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial I(a,b)}{\partial (a^2)}&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{a^2+b^2\tan^2(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{\pi/2}{a(a+b)}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Integrating $(1)$ with respect to $a^2$, we obtain

$$I(a,b)=\pi \log(a+b)+C$$

For $a=b$, $I(a,a)=\pi \log(a)$ from which we find that $C=-\pi\log(2)$.

Putting it all together yields

$$I(a,b)=\pi \log\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)$$

---

> **NOTE:**

We see from symmetry that  $I(a,b)=\pi \log\left(\frac{|a|+|b|}2\right)$   $\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus (0,0)$.

Comment: Now both of you( Mark and Jack)  have put in trouble.  Both of your answers are marvelous in its own way. So which one to accept.

Comment: Nope. Correction here.  It is also applicable for $ab=0$ except for the case $a=b=0$

Comment: @Manthanein Good catch. I'll edit.

Comment: Try $b=0$ and $a$ be some finite number. Now the integrals changes to $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(a^2\cos^2\theta )d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(a\cos\theta )d\theta=2\left[\frac {\pi}{2}\ln a-\frac {\pi}{2}\ln 2\right]=\pi\ln (a/2)$$ which matches with the general form you derived

Comment: @Manthanein It should match, should it not?

Comment: I have edited your answer, please check if it's correct or not. And yes it should definitely match

Comment: @Manthanein Yes, it is correct.  Apology for my being sloppy.  I've edited again with bit tighter language.

Comment: No problem and thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure.  And pleased this was useful.

Answer (score 5):

If we assume $a,b>0$ and set 
$$ I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta)\,d\theta $$
we have $I(a,b)=I(b,a)$ from the substitution $\theta\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$. On the other hand $I(a,a)=\pi\log(a)$ is trivial, so $I(a,b)=\pi\log\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ is a very reasonable conjecture. Indeed, it can be proved by computing 
$$ \frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2a\cos^2\theta}{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta $$
as suggested in the comments, i.e. via $\theta\mapsto\arctan u$ and partial fraction decomposition.

An alternative approach is to notice that
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(a,b) &=& 2\,\text{Re}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(a\cos\theta+ib\sin\theta\right)\\&=&\pi\log\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+\text{Re}\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left(e^{i\theta}+\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)\,d\theta\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the last integral is a purely imaginary number by the residue theorem.

Comment: Now both of you( Mark and Jack)  have put in trouble.  Both of your answers are marvelous in its own way. So which one to accept.

Comment: And by the way no need to assume $a, b\gt 0$, it's already provided in in question that they are natural numbers

Comment: @Manthanein We need not assume that $a$ and $b$ are positive.  Note that since the integral depends on $a^2$ and $b^2$, then the answer depends on $|a|$ and $|b|$ only.

Comment: @Mark Viola That is what I said.  Morever the modulus will be removed since they are natural and always positive

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts, then substitute $u=\tan\theta$ :

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \ln\left(a^2\cos^2\theta + b^2\sin^2\theta\right) \, d\theta \\
&= \pi\ln a + \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \ln\left(1 + \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right) \sin^2\theta\right) \, d\theta \\
&= \pi \ln b - 2\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right) \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\theta \sin\theta \cos\theta}{1 + \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right) \sin^2\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \pi \ln b - 2\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right) \int_0^\infty \frac{u \arctan u}{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2} u^2 + 1\right)} \, du 
\end{align*}$$

Now, for some real $\beta\neq0$, let

$$J(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty \frac{u \arctan(\alpha u)}{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(\beta^2u^2+1\right)} \, du \quad [I(0)=0]$$

Differentiate w.r.t. $\alpha$ and evaluate the subsequent integral. Partial fractions are our friend.

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha} = \int_0^\infty \frac{u^2}{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(\beta^2u^2+1\right) \left(\alpha^2u^2+1\right)} = \frac\pi{2\left(\beta^2-1\right)} \left[\frac1{\alpha+1} - \frac1{\alpha+\beta}\right]$$

Integrate w.r.t. $\alpha$:

$$J(\alpha) = \frac\pi{2\left(\beta^2-1\right)} \int_0^\alpha \left(\frac1{t+1} - \frac1{t+\beta}\right) \, dt = \frac\pi{2\left(\beta^2-1\right)} \ln \frac{\beta(\alpha+1)}{\alpha+\beta}$$

Finally, replace $\beta=\dfrac ba$ and let $\alpha\to1$ to recover $I$:

$$J(1) = \frac{\pi a^2}{2\left(b^2-a^2\right)} \ln \frac{2b}{a+b} \implies \boxed{I = \pi \ln \frac{a+b}2}$$

Comment: That is quite a tedious way forward.  But it does work. ;-) So (+1)

Comment: If one *really* wants to get one's hands dirty, $J(1)$ can be written in terms of $J(a,b,c)$ as defined in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397742/how-do-solve-this-integral-int-11-frac1-sqrt1-x2-arctan-frac11-6/4821505#4821505)

Answer (score 1):

Let $r= \frac{a-b}{a+b}$
\begin{align}
& \int^{{\pi}/{2}}_{0}\ln{\left(a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t\right)}dt\\
 = & \int^{\pi/2}_{0}
\bigg[2\ln\frac{a+b}2+ \ln(1+r^2 -2r\cos 2t)\bigg] dt = \pi\ln\frac{a+b}2 
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
& \int^{{\pi}/{2}}_{0} \ln(1+r^2 -2r\cos 2t) dt\\
 = & \int^{\pi/2}_{0}
\int_0^{r}
\frac{2s-2\cos2t}{1+s^2 -2s\cos 2t}ds \ dt\\
 = &\ \int_0^{r}
 \left(\frac1s\tan^{-1}
\frac{s\sin2t}{s\cos 2t-1}\right)_{t=0}^{t=\frac\pi2}ds
= \int_0^r 0 \ ds=0
\end{align}