# Limit of a sequence with parameter.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How do I find the limit of the following sequence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^r}{n^{r+1}}.$$

Comment: It's a limit of a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recognize a Riemann sum, by writing,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^r}{n^{r+1}}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{r}.
$$

Comment: Hope you know this result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987358/calculate-an-integral-with-riemann-sum

Comment: Is there any solution that does not include integrals?

Comment: Yes there is. We have $\sum_{k=1}^n k^r= \frac{(n+1)^{r+1}}{r+1} + \cdots$ from which you may deduce the sought limit. Have a look here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Some_summations_of_polynomial_expressions or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula