# Difficult limit of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I need a help. There is a limit of an infinite sum I can't calculate. Here it is:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(b-1)n}{(j(b-1)+n)^2}=???,\quad\text{($b$=const)}.$$

I haven't got any ideas of how to solve this. But I know that the answer should be $1-\frac{1}{b}$ (it is an area under $y=x^{-2}$ from $1$ to $b$, $b>1$). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note  that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(b-1)n}{(j(b-1)+n)^2}=\frac{(b-1)}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(\frac{j}{n}(b-1)+1)^2}$$
Now the keyword is [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). See also [Calculate an integral with Riemann sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987358/calculate-an-integral-with-riemann-sum)

Comment: Thanks! Your post is very useful!