# Evaluating a challenging definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

Evaluate the following integral: $$I=\int_0^{\pi} \ln(a^2-2a\cos x+1) \,dx$$

My attempt: Letting $t=\pi-x$

$$I=\int_0^{\pi} \ln(a^2+2a\cos t+1) \,dt$$
Adding both equations,
$$2I=\int_0^{\pi} \ln(a^2+2a\cos x+1)((a^2-2a\cos x+1)) \,dx$$
$$\implies 2I=\int_0^{\pi}\ln(a^4-2a^2\cos 2x+1)dx$$

I don't think applying integration by parts will yield an answer and no substitution seems to be evident here. The final answer given at the end of the worksheet is $2\pi\ln a$. How do I go about evaluating this integral? Is there a clever method to find the primitive of this function?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573554/calculating-int-0-pi-log1-2a-cos-xa2-dx?noredirect=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650513/computing-int-0-pi-ln-left1-2a-cos-xa2-right-dx

Comment: Ah, this is a duplicate, my bad. thanks a lot for pointing that out @Svyatoslav.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a>0$. If $a>1$,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^{\pi} \ln(a^2-2a\cos x+1) \,dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \ln(a^2-2a\cos x+1) \,dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \ln((a-\cos x)^2+\sin^2x) \,dx\\
&=&\int_0^{2\pi} \ln|a-(\cos x+i\sin x)| \,dx\\
&\overset{z=e^{ix}}=&\Re\int_{|z|=1} \ln(a-z) \frac1{iz}dz\\
&=&\Re\bigg[2\pi\text{Res}\bigg(\ln(a-z),z=0\bigg)\bigg]\\
&=&2\pi\ln a.
\end{eqnarray}$$
If $a\in(0,1)$, set $b=\frac1a$ and hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^{\pi} \ln(a^2-2a\cos x+1) \,dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi} \ln\bigg[a^2(1-2b\cos x+b^2)\bigg] \,dx\\
&=&2\pi\ln a+\int_0^{\pi} \ln(b^2-2b\cos x+1) \,dx\\
&=&2\pi\ln a+2\pi\ln b\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}$$
If $a=1$,
$$ I=\int_0^{\pi} \ln(2-2\cos x) \,dx=0. $$
You can treat the same way when $a<0$.

Comment: Uh, I got lost in the step after you converted it into the Riemann sum. What exactly do you do in the fifth and sixth line in your answer?

Comment: @Cognoscenti he converted it to a contour integral about the unit circle, and then applied the residue theorem. (Have you learned complex analysis yet? If not then rip)

Comment: I unfortunately haven't but I think I'll read up a bit on it and try my best to understand!